# python, given 2 lists, take off the same middle part then added rest 2 lists

Tags: python, list

In python, need to define a function that takes 2 lists. If the last part of the first list is same as first part of the second list, then delete the same part and added rest 2 lists together. such as:

I have defined a helper function called prefix that takes 2 lists and return true if the first list is prefix of the second list. Otherwise return false.

Comment: What did Prefix do? And fix your indentation.

Comment: What's the expected output when merging `[1,2,3]` and `[2,3,4]`?

Comment: If you'll format your code properly, you'll be more likely to get a good answer.

Comment: The expect output of when merging [1,2,3] and [2,3,4] should be [1,2,3,4] because [2,3] is prefix of the second list, it should only appear once, so just delete [2,3] in list one, then add up new list one and the original list two

Comment: This is your first of three "do my homework for me" question you posted.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
def merge(seq1, seq2):
    n1 = len(seq1)
    for i in range(n1):
        if seq1[i:] == seq2[:n1-i]:
            return seq1 + seq2[n1-i:]
    return seq1 + seq2

In [52]: merge(['a','a','a'],['g','g','g'])
Out[52]: ['a', 'a', 'a', 'g', 'g', 'g']

In [53]: merge(['a','t','t','a'],['t','t','a','a'])
Out[53]: ['a', 't', 't', 'a', 'a']

In [54]: merge(['a','t','t','a'],['t','t','a','a'])
Out[54]: ['a', 't', 't', 'a', 'a']

In [55]: merge(['a', 'a', 'a', 't', 't', 't', 't'], ['t', 't', 't', 't', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g'])
Out[55]: ['a', 'a', 'a', 't', 't', 't', 't', 'g', 'g', 'g', 'g']
```

It doesn't modify the original lists, but you could do this easily if you need to.
(This isn't the way to go if your lists are very long with short overlaps because it checks from the beginning of the first.)

Answer (score 0):

```html
def merge(L1, L2):
    middle = []
    while L1 and L2 and L1[-1] == L2[0]:
        middle.append(L2[0])
        L1 = L1[:-2]
        L2 = L2[1:]
    return L1 + middle + L2
```

Comment: umm. Thanks for your answer. Your answer works for some test cases. However, I tested one more case, seems it is not working.That is:                    >>> merge(['a','t','t','a'],['t','t','a','a'])
['a', 't', 't', 'a', 't', 't', 'a', 'a'], I think the answer should be ['a', 't', 't', 'a', 'a']. And, what is LI[-1]? I thought the index of a list start from 0, how comes -1?

Comment: Nick, the 'a' at the end of your first list does not match the 't' at the beginning of the second list so no elements are being removed.  Therefore, based on my understanding of the question, [a, t, t, a, t, t, a, a] is the correct output.

The negative list index means take the elements from the end of the list instead of the beginning.  List index -1 is the last list element, -2 is the second to last element, etc.